# Meaning of “discount”

Tags: finance

If someone is advertising a “reservation discount” of 75000, does that mean

A. The final price will be 75000 or

B. The final price will be original price - 75000

?

Answer (score 4):

A **reservation discount** of 75000 means that:

> The final price will be original price - 75000

The term 'a discount of...' means that the price will be reduced by the amount specified.